# I cannot fill the textarea editors which are created with CKEditor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, textarea

I am developing an Administration Panel, and want to fill the textarea editors with the data coming from the database. When I create the editors with CKEditors, I cannot fill in the data. When I use the input tag, I can fill it.
Also, I checked the data coming from the database, it seems OK.
I used the below structures, but they did not work.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertText( part[0] );

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( part[0] );

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( “hello” );
```

Below is my code. I am new to PHP and jQuery. Where did I make mistake?

I created the editors like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="adapters/jquery.js"></script>
    
    <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let editor1;
        let editor2;
        let editor3;
        let editor4;
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor1'), {
                heading: {
                    options: [{
                        model: 'heading1',
                        view: 'h1',
                        title: 'Heading 1',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading1'
                    }, {
                        model: 'heading2',
                        view: 'h2',
                        title: 'Heading 2',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading2'
                    }, {
                        model: 'heading3',
                        view: 'h3',
                        title: 'Heading 3',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading3'
                    }, {
                        model: 'heading4',
                        view: 'h4',
                        title: 'Heading 4',
                        class: 'ck-heading_heading4'
                    }]
                },
                toolbar: ['Heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'undo', 'redo']
            })
            .then(editor =>{
                editor1 = editor;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor2'), {

            })
            .then(editor =>{
                editor2 = editor;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
            ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor4'), {

            })
            .then(editor =>{
                editor4 = editor;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
        ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor3'), {
                toolbar: ['imageInsert'],
                ckfinder: {
                    // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
                    uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
                }
            })
            .then(editor =>{
                editor3 = editor;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
            ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor5'), {

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    </script>
     <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#example1").DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
            }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
           
        });
        ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor6'), {
                toolbar: ['imageInsert'],
                ckfinder: {
                    // Upload the images to the server using the CKFinder QuickUpload command.
                    uploadUrl: 'https://example.com/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
    </script>
```

My jQuery code is here:

```
<script>
    function selectService(id)
    {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                console.log(this.responseText);

                var parts = xmlhttp.responseText.split('**');
                console.log(parts); //part0=title, part1=description, part2=photo, part3=sequenceNo

                document.getElementById("editor1").value = parts[0]; //title
                document.getElementById("editor3").value = parts[2]; //photo
                document.getElementById("editor2").value = parts[1]; //description
                document.getElementById("sequenceNo").value = parts[3]; //sequenceNo

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "selectService.php?id=" + id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
</script>
```

I am using the editors like this:

```
<tbody>
                                <tr id="#editors">
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <textarea id="editor3" name="editor3"></textarea>
                                          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <textarea id="editor2"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <input id="sequenceNo">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm" onclick="detay()">Detay Ekle</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-sm" onclick="save()">Kaydet</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-sm">Vazgeç</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                            </tbody>
```

Comment: If you initialize the editor before fetching the data you need to use the editor api to setContent. Or initialize the editor after you set the value of the textarea